# page.js is not rendering in app routing, instead I keep getting not-found.js

Tags: next.js, app-router

I'm migrating my next js application from page to app routing and I created the RootLayout, page and not-found inside my app folder as mentioned in the docs.

I tried to debug via console and I get the log in my RootLayout but my page is not rendered and I get not-found.js code rendered.

This is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: You also need to create layout.tsx or layout.jsx and page.tsx or page.jsx inside app directory. Have you created that ?

Comment: Yes, I've added both the layout.js and page.js. Here's my structure:

`- src
  - app
    - layout.js
    - page.js
    - not-found.js`

Comment: You need to create jsx not just js file in nextjs

Comment: But as per the Next.js docs, it says .js can be used as well.

Comment: Can you attach your app directory folder image on your question ? so I can see how you have created files inside the folder.

Comment: Also please attach layout.jsx and page.jsx

Comment: So I figured it out and found that I had an index.js file inside my pages directory which was causing the conflict. I removed the index.js file from my pages directory and page.js of app directory worked fine.